# Use curl instead of file_get_contents in function

Tags: php, wordpress, file, file-get-contents

Below my code for loading and storing a xml-feed. Important is also the time-out in case the feed is offline or responds to slow.

Some users do not have file_get_contents enabled. I'm looking for a way to change this to curl or do a check and use the one that is enabled. And not lose the functionality to set a time out. Any ideas?

```
    function feeder()
    {
    $cache_time = 3600 * 12; // 12 hours
    $cache_file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/cache/feed.xml';
    $timedif = @(time() - filemtime($cache_file));
    $fc_xml_options = get_option('fc_xml_options');
    $xml_feed = $fc_xml_options['feed'];

    // remove white space(s) and/or space(s) from connector code

    $xml_feed = str_replace(' ', '', $xml_feed);
    $xml_feed = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $xml_feed);
    if (file_exists($cache_file) && $timedif < $cache_time)
        {
        $string = file_get_contents($cache_file);
        }
      else
        {
        // set a time-out (5 sec) on fetch feed
        $xml_context = array( 'http' => array(
              'timeout'       => 5,
          ) );
        $pure_context = stream_context_create($xml_context);

        $string = file_get_contents($xml_feed, false, $pure_context);
        if ($f = @fopen($cache_file, 'w'))
            {
            fwrite($f, $string, strlen($string));
            fclose($f);
            }
        }
```

Comment: start translating? we fix code, we don't translate/rewrite it for you... and if f_g_c() isn't available, you might want to consider that curl won't be either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use curl to read local file. Just change url to file path prefixed by `file://`

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "file://full_path_to_file"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);
```